# change value of selected RadioSelect field in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

How can i change the value of the selected choice rendered as RadioSelect field in django? ....... ---newbie Thanks...

template

```
<div class="row"><div class="boxed_content">Classification of Research<br>
                            {% for rdo in form.classif_res %}
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                {{ rdo }}
                            </div>  
                            {% endfor %}
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="classif_other" id="res_classifcation" />

                    </div></div>
```

the model field is a TextField with one of the choices named as "Others."
what i want to do is whenever the user selects "Others" the data that will be saved is the value from the textbox in the template....

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of a solution instead of changing the value selected.... i added a new field and named it other_classif  which will be rendered as a textbox then i added some script for it to be enabled only if the radio-other is selected. But if anyone has a better way please feel free to add answers to my problem. Thank you and have a good day .